# Up and down view rotation is limited in walk navigation

Tags: navigation

As can be seen in the GIF i cannot rotate down or up freely as in regular view port (not in walk navigatio) any setting i am missing or is this a set behavior ?

Additional info: as I drag the mouse down while clicking the middle mouse button not in walk navigation I can rotate endlessly and freely. whilst in walk navigation I reach a limit and cannot rotate anymore

[image: limited navigation]

Comment: I can't tell anything from that gif.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.